# Select data within specified time periods in a day SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to get items received within different specified time periods within a day. An output like this;
[image: SQL Output]

Do anyone have idea how i can implement a sql query to return result table like this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: show some sample data and your attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT Item,
  SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(DateTimeCol AS Time) >= '08:00:00' AND CAST(DateTimeCol AS Time) < '10:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [8AM-10AM],
  SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(DateTimeCol AS Time) >= '10:00:00' AND CAST(DateTimeCol AS Time) < '12:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [8AM-10AM],
  SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(DateTimeCol AS Time) >= '12:00:00' AND CAST(DateTimeCol AS Time) < '14:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [10AM-12AM],
  SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(DateTimeCol AS Time) >= '14:00:00' AND CAST(DateTimeCol AS Time) < '16:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [12PM-2PM],
  SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(DateTimeCol AS Time) >= '16:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)                                            AS [>4PM]
FROM table1
GROUP BY Item;
```

- [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/21b89/10)

**Sample Results**:

```
|   Item | 8AM-10AM | 10AM-12AM | 12PM-2PM | 2AM-4PM | >4PM |
|--------|----------|-----------|----------|---------|------|
| Item 1 |        2 |         4 |        1 |       0 |    0 |
| Item 2 |        0 |         0 |        1 |       2 |    2 |
```

---

**Update:**

You can use the `PIVOT` table operator with temporary table with all the time ranges as following:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    Item,
    Alias
  FROM Table1
  INNER JOIN Ranges  ON CAST(DateTimeCol AS TIME) >= [Start] 
                    AND CAST(DateTimeCol AS TIME) < [End]
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(Alias)
  FOR Alias IN([8AM-10AM], [10AM-12AM], [12PM-2PM],[2PM-4PM], [>4PM])
 ) AS p;
```

- [pivot demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2832f/3)

Comment: @MartinSmith Sorry It was `between` then forgot to fix it, thanks

Comment: Also `BETWEEN` is inclusive so you will be counting hour 10 twice etc. So your 9 example rows produce a result of 12.

Comment: @MartinSmith -Thanks a lot I fixed it now, but how can this be written in `PIVOT` table operator is that posssible??

Comment: Yes, you’d need to add a calculated column with the “bucket” the time relates to then pivot on that.

Comment: PIVOT we can write by getting these values into a temporary table. right?